# Problems transferring variables into ob

Tags: php, variables, buffer

I use the following code to read a template into the buffer (ob).  $vars contains all the variables i want to have access to in the template.

```
print_r($this->vals);  //prints out an array of values, value1 => '', value2 => ''...
ob_start();
include myTemplate.php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $content;
```

But then in my template $vals is undefined or i don't have access to it.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't assign $vals or $vars anywhere in your example. Naturally both variables will be undefined. You may want to show us some more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

May be a simple typo error. But you are using `$vals` instead of `$vars`.

And if this is not the problem put `ob_start()` at top.

```
ob_start();
print_r($this->vals);  //prints out an array of values, value1 => '', value2 => ''...
include "myTemplate.php"; //few errors were here, no quotes and semicolon
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $content;
```

Just did a quick test, it works.

---

### Update

In case you are trying to get the value of `print_r($this -> vals)` to `$content`. There is a very easy way to do this. print_r()*<sup>[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)</sup>* function take another argument as well whether to return or not.

If so, your entire code comes down to this

```
$content = print_r($this->vals, true);
```

Comment: @rix: That doesn't help at all. You are not trying to assign variables with `print_r` and `ob_start`, are you?

Comment: @Basti, I guess, he is trying to get the values of print_r to the Content;